# I got big white screen when i attach main style sheet of Html in functions.php

Tags: php, functions, css

I am new here on @stack Enchange .

Here is an issue on my work . I hope you gyies can help me in this

When I attach main style sheet in function.php . a white screen occur in front end. after inspecting element all style sheet and java script are attached and html is also running very well as need . it is showing in inspect element. I have increased the memory limit , and define the debug log true as well

Here is my code

Note : I am getting error when i am attaching this

> wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css',
>   array(), 1, 'all'); wp_enqueue_style('style');

Comment: Try using this : **wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );**

Comment: I have tried that but screen shown still the same .

Comment: function load_stylesheets() {
wp_register_style('style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css', array(), 1, 'all');
wp_enqueue_style('style');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');

Comment: CSS is loading and Html is also loading but it is howing white screen . You move page up and down as well

Comment: getting white screen when i attach main style sheet of html in function.php. 

What i have already done

I have checked with debug , memory limit. 
I have checked memory limit.
All CSS and javascript attached i have checked in console mode  
Html and css are loading completely no error in that . 

Here is code

Comment: did you check in style.css file ? what css code inside ? remove all css code except Theme Name: commented code. see if there is issue.

Comment: I have rename that file to main.css and created new file style .css . but after that also it is not working . but when i unattach the file Html is loading properly

Comment: did you enqueue main.css file ? then probably issue in that file. please check after removing code from css file.

Comment: The white screen means execution has stopped due to an error. You need to be running in debug mode so the error is displayed. Without the error information included, any answers you get are going to be guesses. In your wp-config, set WP_DEBUG to true.

Comment: Yes when i use this css in my style sheet it is giving white page 


body:not(.no-transition) #wrapper,
.animsition-overlay {
 position: relative;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
}

Comment: Your CSS sets the body opacity to 0, so of course it's going white. Why are you adding this CSS?

Comment: thanks @jacob Peattie thats is the answer i got my mistake. Some time silly things consume time